# CentOS 7 - Isolated cores are not isolated in practice

Tags: centos, grub, kernel-parameters

I have a pair of CentOS 7 servers (7.9.2009) with 8 physical CPUs each.
Out of those, I'm trying to isolate cores 4-8 (so 3-7 as the OS sees them).

I added the tag `isolcpus=3-7` to `/etc/default/grub` after the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` parameter, ran `grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/efi/EFI/centos/grub.cfg` to generate a new configuration file and rebooted.

Both servers respected the setting, as seen in `/sys/devices/system/cpu/isolated` - it shows cores 3-7 as I specified.

However, on *one* of the servers, only one of the supposedly cores has system processes running on it (`systemd`,`lvmetad` and such) - despite several restarts, the OS does not seem to respect the core isolation in practice.

I use the `numactl` command to see which cores are isolated as well, and output does differ between the servers (command is `numactl -s | grep physcpubind`:

Server 1 (respects isolation):

`physcpubind: 0 1 2 3`

Server 2 (does not respect isolation):

`physcpubind: 4 5 6 7`

I'm quite lost as to what could be causing this and how to resolve this - any tips would be  greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Where are your CPUs 0-3 on the 2nd server?

Based on your numactl output you appear to have only 4-7 online for some reason and if you are isolating it, then the kernel is ignoring your isolcpus parameter because you can't isolate the boot CPU. Maybe try `isolcpus=0-3,5-7` or `isolcpus=5-7` to confirm. Note that isolating CPUs past the last online CPU can also have the same effect but also depend on the hardware information provided to the kernel, so it may work in some cases and not in others.

The output of `lscpu -p` from both servers would help troubleshooting further. Also look in dmesg after boot for any unusual message related to the cpus or isolcpus command line option.